# Using logical operators in shooting robot program

Tags: c#

Here is the c# code that controls an artillery shooting robot.

```
static bool ShouldFire(bool enemyInFront, string enemyName, int robotHealth)
{
    bool shouldFire = true;
    if (enemyInFront == true)
    {
        if (enemyName == "boss")
        {
            if (robotHealth < 50) shouldFire = false;
            if (robotHealth > 100) shouldFire = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return shouldFire;
}
```

The code looks awkward somewhat and could be re-written significantly shorter. Can the community at stackoverflow suggest a c# method, that would do the same as in the code above, but using one operation? I kindly ask you to make your proposals. Here is some template of what one is looking for:

```
static bool ShouldFire2(bool enemyInFront, string enemyName, int robotHealth)
{
    return enemyInFront && (...);
}
```

I would appreciate some explanation, on how to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Hi @shepengauer, welcome to SO!  This question is probably better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  SO is for [asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211790)  about problems with your code and/or why something isn't working

Comment: `return enemyInFront && (enemyName != "boss" || robotHealth >= 50);`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I reran my code with the function enemyInFront and your return line and it worked exactly the same way as the original code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review.

Comment: @Greg, thanks for your comment. I will take this into account that such questions do not belong to SO. I will use Code Review instead next time. Kind regards, Shepengauer

Comment: to me this is a perfect case to leave the code as is. its keeping it clear and extensible.

Comment: return (enemyInFront && enemyName == "boss" && robotHealth > 100) ? true : false;

Comment: @Hassaan to your suggestion, return (enemyInFront && enemyName == "boss" && robotHealth > 100) ?, I got the following comment:  "Functions are different on the input (True, "boss", 50)"

Comment: this is off-topic but `if(enemyInFront == true)` should be just `if(enemyInFront)`

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is this:

```
static bool ShouldFire2(bool enemyInFront, string enemyName, int robotHealth)
{
    return enemyInFront && (enemyName == "boss" ? robotHealth >= 50 : true);
}
```

You first check in there is an enemy ahead. if yes, check if it is `boss` and if its hp greater than 50 then return true, otherwise false. If not a boss, always return true. And false if nothing in front of your character.

Comment: Thanks. But, code approver says, that in that case: "Functions are different on the input (True, "boss", 10)"

Comment: sorry for the wrong condition. I fixed it

Comment: Functions are the same, now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The line 'if (robotHealth > 100) shouldFire = true;' does nothing. shouldFire is already true unless health is under 50.

So you can reduce that section to:

```
static bool ShouldFire(bool enemyInFront, string enemyName, int robotHealth)
{
    bool shouldFire = true;
    if (enemyInFront == true)
    {
        return !(enemyName != "boss" && robotHealth < 50);      }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return shouldFire;
}
```

Which could be reduced to:

```
static bool ShouldFire(bool enemyInFront, string enemyName, int robotHealth)
{
    return enemyInFront && (enemyName != "boss" || robotHealth >= 50);
}
```